# how to upload Image Array (Pillow Object) in Python to Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, python-imaging-library

Hi i have this snippet of code that looks like this

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from PIL import Image 

# Use PIL instead of cv2. 
image = Image.fromarray((image_1).astype(np.uint8))
plt.imshow(image)
image.save("test.jpg")
```

so I want to run this function on Cloud Function. Is there a way for me that I don't need to make it a file first with `image.save("file.jpg")` and just straight upload the ImageArray to Google Cloud bucket ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, using Python with GCS, you have 3 functions to upload a file to a bucket.

- [upload_from_file_name](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_filename) :
  You need a path to your file.
- [upload_from_file](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_file) :
  You need an File type object.
- [upload_from_string](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_string):
  You can pass raw data (bytes or str)

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you need, but maybe the third option could be useful.